# Column Chart not dynamic in Fusion Tables API Visualization

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, dom-events, google-fusion-tables

My column chart is not dynamic. Its not changing when I select the county. I am using the same same code as the one given in fusion tables API advanced visualization. What could be the problem?

```
 function drawVisualization(County) {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: "visualization",
      dataSourceUrl: "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
      query: "SELECT Environment,'BoyPupils','GirlPupils'" +
          "FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s WHERE County = '" + County + "'",
      chartType: "ColumnChart",
      options: {
        title: County,
        height: 400,
        width: 400
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: How is the code you posted being used?

Comment: This code is used to draw the visualization. The chart is showing but its not dynamic

Comment: That is what you said in your question.  The code you posted takes a "County" as an argument. Why would you expect the county to change unless you call it differently? Perhaps an explanation of what you mean by "dynamic" might help, or a demonstration of the issue.

Comment: I want to query the chart using different counties, when I select a county, the chart should change `      <label>County</label>
      <select id="County">
        <option value="Kisumu">Kisumu</option>
        <option value="Kakamega">Kakamega</option>
        <option value="Kilifi">Kilifi</option>
        <option value="Nakuru">Nakuru</option>
        <option value="Migori">Migori</option>
        <option value="Kericho">Kericho</option>
        <option value="Trans-Nzoia">Trans-Nzoia</option>
      </select>
    </form>`

Comment: Please update your question with that information, it is difficult to read code or html posted in comments. Do you have an `onchange` listener on the select list that runs this function with an argument that depends on the selection?